# What is the full form of PMD?

Tags: java, pmd, abbreviation, acronym

I am using `PMD` in my Java project for code review.

Just want to know what the acronym "P.M.D." stands for. I searched on Google but could not find anything. Does anyone know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it is hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know what PMD stands for?

Comment: I was just trying to ask the full form of PMD. I know what it is..just want to know what it stands for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[On the PMD project site](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/meaning.html) you can find that they don't really know the meaning of the PMD letters. They just think the letters sound good together. You can find several "backronyms" to explain it [on the PMD project site](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/meaning.html):

- Pretty Much Done
- Project Mess Detector
- Project Monitoring Directives
- Project Meets Deadline
- Programming Mistake Detector
- Pounds Mistakes Dead
- PMD Meaning Discovery (recursion, hooray!)
- Programs of Mass Destruction
- Programming Meticulous coDe

Answer (score 1):

PMD Meaning Detector (recursion)