# What does PMD stand for?

Tags: java, code-analysis, pmd

I'm talking about [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) source code analyzer.

Does it mean something?
Is it an acronym?
Or it just means nothing?

Sorry for this trivial question, I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a product name. Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the full form of PMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564726/what-is-the-full-form-of-pmd)

Comment: @FilippoLauria: You shouldn't be sorry.  SO should be sorry; it would have been easier to just answer your question than to scold you. I think people are losing sensibility.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, [it doesn't mean anything](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/meaning.html).

From that link:

"We've been trying to find the meaning of the letters PMD - because frankly, we don't really know. We just think the letters sound good together."

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_%28software%29)

> While PMD does not officially stand for anything, it has several unofficial names, the most appropriate probably being Programming Mistake Detector.